# FINDSTR Multiple Search Strings

Tags: cmd.exe, regex, string, findstr

Looking for either word “ And ” or “ In ” with preceding and ending spaces, I can using following FINDSTR command:

```
 findstr /r /c:” And ” /c:” In “ textfile
```

Is there a way to do similar search with only on `/c` parameter? I was hoping this parameter would work: `/c:” (And|In) “`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
findstr /c:" And " textfile | findstr /c:" In "
```

You have not using RegEx so I omitted `/r`. Piping the output may work better.